# Sterile (4th) neutrino and cosmological bound

Tags: cosmology, experimental-physics, neutrinos

Recent results by MicroBoone seems to give support to old LSND experiment in favor of a fourth neutrino (sterile). How does it fit with the current cosmological bound for neutrinos?